# PHP Class scanner

Tags: php, phpdoc

This is maybe rather strange, but I want to make a class scanner.

Let's say, I want to make a REST route, but I am too lazy to write route for each classes. So, my folder is organized as follows:

```
lib
|-router.php
service
|-modulea
  |-this.php
  |-that.php
|-moduleb
  |-notthis.php
  |-notthat.php
```

Inside services classes, I'll put annotation like

```
class This {
   /**
   * @path this/@id
   */
  public function get($id) {
  }
}
```

Now, if I want to scan all classes inside service folder, and then call

`Router->register('this/@id', 'This->get(@id)')`

every time it finds a class with @path annotation

**My question is, what is the best way to implement it?**

1. For scanning, I reckon that it is an expensive process. So I plan to put a scanner, and create a file, that will be rewritten when it detects a change in folder structure. But how can I detect change in folder effectively during call, invalidate cache, and rescan? I really don't want to do rescan for every N times. So I want to do a checksum and rescan only when changes detected. This data file will then be used to feed route data by Router class.
2. For annotation, I plan to follow PHPDoc standard syntax, but what is the effective way to read @path annotation? Should I use ReflectionClass, or is it better to just get_file_contents and parse it? Since I think I won't need to instantiate the class, only to gather all information and put them in a serialized file.

Note: I am NOT looking for framework. I am looking for a way to compile a list of all controllers, and feed them to the framework.

Thank you

Comment: ReflectionClass is great for your purpose. http://php.net/manual/de/class.reflectionclass.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out some of the existing solutions to your problems.

Just to look at annotations, the best option I'm aware of is [Doctrine Annotations](https://github.com/doctrine/annotations)

You also might be interested in an existing routing component, such as [Symfony Router](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing.html) - works as an independent component, including annotations for configuration, or within the Symfony framework.

Comment: As I said, I am too lazy to write all those RouteCollection commands, and plans to scan all controller classes inside service and write a FileLoader to feed.

Comment: Sounds like you just want to download a new Symfony project, its all setup to go, just create a controller class, put `@Route("/somepath")` before a function and everything works. Symfony router uses annotations, no need for a file listing routes

Comment: Ah..found it... SensioFrameworkExtraBundle.. Thank you. Yes.. that will do. I thought Symfony Router can only be feed manually.

Answer (score 0):

you can use symfony routing system to do this. Install in your project the router component `composer require symfony/routing`